# Seeing an error in output (Ruby language)

Tags: ruby, shopify, liquid-template

This a code of product recommendations section which shows related products on cart and product details page

```
{% assign itemsPerColumn = columns | times:1 %}
{% assign perCol = count_product | divided_by: itemsPerColumn | ceil %}
{% assign leftOver = count_product | modulo: itemsPerColumn %}
{% assign numCols = perCol | plus: (leftOver > 0) | plus: (count_product == 1) %}
{% for row in (1..rows) %}
  <div class="row">
    {% for column in (1..columns) %}
      {% assign index = (forloop.index0 | times: rows) | plus: row | minus: 1 %}
      {% if index < count_product %}
        {% assign product = products[index] %}
        {% include 'product-card', max_height: max_height, product: product, show_vendor: show_vendor %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

i am seeing this error and cant find the solution:

```
Liquid syntax error (snippets/gp-product-related line 4): Expected dotdot but found comparison in "{{perCol | plus: (leftOver > 0) | plus: (count_product == 1) }}
```

I tried using module and removing parenthesis

Comment: What is this supposed to do? `assign numCols = perCol | plus: (leftOver > 0)`

Comment: I think parentheses are invalid characters in Liquid, hence the error. But I can't really suggest how to rewrite that code without understanding it.

Comment: Here's what's happening:

perCol represents the desired number of items per column in the grid.
leftOver represents the number of items that will be left over after filling complete columns.
The line of code in question is using the plus filter to add 1 to perCol for each leftover item. In other words, if there are any leftover items, an extra column will be added to the grid to accommodate them.

The result of this calculation is then assigned to the variable numCols, which represents the total number of columns needed to display the related products in the grid layout.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because parentheses are not valid syntax in Liquid.

But to be honest, most of your problem is the poorly named variables (and redundant code). Let's look line-by-line, and I'll point out all the weird things I see:

---

```
{% assign itemsPerColumn = columns | times:1 %}
```

What's going on here? Couldn't you just pass `itemsPerColumn` to the template, instead of a poorly-named `columns` variable?

And what's the point of `times: 1`? That's redundant code, delete it.

---

```
{% assign perCol = count_product | divided_by: itemsPerColumn | ceil %}
```

Another poorly named variable. This looks like you should be assigning `numberOfColumns` here.

Additionally, you're mixing `camelCase` with `snake_case`. Usually in ruby it's conventional to use `snake_case` for all variables, but both styles are valid... However, it's best to be consistent in which style you're using!

---

```
{% assign leftOver = count_product | modulo: itemsPerColumn %}
```

I'd call this `leftOverItemsCount`, not a vaguely-named `leftOver`. (Although again, we're mixing `camelCase` with `snake_case`...)

---

```
{% assign numCols = perCol | plus: (leftOver > 0) | plus: (count_product == 1) %}
```

The fatal error: Parentheses are not valid syntax in Liquid!

This code is actually not needed at all (as I'll show below), but you could write this logic in some way like:

```
{% assign numCols = perCol %}
{% if leftOver > 0 %}
  {% increment numCols %}
{% endif %}
{% if count_product == 1 %}
  {% increment numCols %}
{% endif %}
```

---

Now, back to my main answer. If we rename all of your variables to what they *really* represent, the logic becomes quite simple actually:

```
{% assign number_of_columns = count_product | divided_by: items_per_column | ceil %}
{% assign left_over_items_count = count_product | modulo: number_of_columns %}
```